# Simple React Native iOS App is not running in xcode and command line

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I try to create a new React Native project with:

```
react-native init projectname
```

and I open . xcworkspace & hit run

=> error:

```
'cxxreact/ModuleRegistry.h' file not found
```

or

```
react-native init projectname
react-native run-ios
```

=> error:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening testproj060.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: I am learner react-native .i have setup in MacBook Air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pod installation issue use below steps

1. brew insatll cocoapods
2. cd projectName/ios
3. pod install
4. cd .. & react-native run-ios